# Como fazer uma busca no banco de dados com JpaRepository buscando por um guid ID?

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, rest

Estou utilizando Spring boot para criar uma api para um trabalho da faculdade e estou tentando fazer uma busca no banco de dados através de um guid id e estou tendo um retorno vazio e não sei como fazer para fazer essa busca

**Retorno no postman**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Select no banco de dados**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minha Controller**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/senhas")
public class PasswordController {

    private PasswordService passwordService;

    public PasswordController(PasswordService passwordService) {
        this.passwordService = passwordService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/senhasuser")
    public ResponseEntity<List<SenhaModel>> listarSenhasUsuario(@RequestHeader UUID idUser) {
        List<SenhaModel> senhas = passwordService.findUserPasswords(idUser);
        return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(senhas);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> cadastrarSenha(@RequestBody SenhaModel senha) throws ParseException {
        return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(passwordService.insert(senha));
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> deletarSenha(@RequestHeader UUID idUser) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(passwordService.deleteById(idUser));
    }

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> AlterarSenha(@RequestHeader UUID idSenha, @RequestBody UpdatePasswordModel data)
            throws ParseException {
        return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(passwordService.updatePassword(idSenha, data));
    }
}
```

**Minha service**

```
@Service
public class PasswordService {

    private PasswordRepository passwordRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public PasswordService(PasswordRepository passwordRepository) {
        this.passwordRepository = passwordRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public List<SenhaModel> findUserPasswords(UUID idUser) {
        List<SenhaModel> senhas = passwordRepository.findSenhasByIdUser(idUser);
        return senhas;
    }

    public SenhaModel insert(SenhaModel senha) throws ParseException {
        String titulo = senha.getTitulo().toUpperCase();
        senha.setTitulo(titulo);

        String encoder = this.passwordEncoder.encode(senha.getSenha());
        senha.setSenha(encoder);

        Date currentDate = DateAdministrator.currentDate();
        senha.setDataCriacao(currentDate);

        passwordRepository.save(senha);
        return senha;
    }

    public SenhaModel findByGuidId(UUID idPass) {
        return passwordRepository.findByGuidId(idPass);
    }

    public SenhaModel deleteById(UUID idPass) {
        SenhaModel senhaDelete = findByGuidId(idPass);
        passwordRepository.deleteById(idPass);
        return senhaDelete;
    }

    public boolean updatePassword(UUID idSenha, UpdatePasswordModel data) throws ParseException {
        SenhaModel passwordAtt = findByGuidId(idSenha);

        String upperTitulo = data.getTitulo().toUpperCase();
        String encoder = passwordEncoder.encode(data.getSenha());
        Date dateNow = DateAdministrator.currentDate();

        passwordAtt.setTitulo(upperTitulo);
        passwordAtt.setSenha(encoder);
        passwordAtt.setDataAlteracao(dateNow);

        passwordRepository.save(passwordAtt);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Meu repository**

```
import edu.senac.demo.model.SenhaModel;

public interface PasswordRepository extends JpaRepository<SenhaModel, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SenhaModel> {

    public final static String FIND_USER_PASSWORDS = "SELECT * FROM TB_SENHA WHERE ID_USER = :idUser";
    public final static String FIND_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM TB_SENHA WHERE ID_SENHA = :idSenha";

    @Query(value = FIND_USER_PASSWORDS, nativeQuery = true)
    public List<SenhaModel> findSenhasByIdUser(@Param("idUser") final UUID idUser);

    @Query(value = FIND_BY_ID, nativeQuery = true)
    public SenhaModel findByGuidId(@Param("idSenha") final UUID idSenha);
}
```

**Banco de dados**

```
    CREATE TABLE TB_SENHA (
    ID_SENHA             VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    TITULO               VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SENHA                VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    DATA_CRIACAO         DATE NOT NULL,
    DATA_ALTERACAO       DATE,
    ID_USER              VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_USER) REFERENCES TB_USER(ID_USER)
    );
```

Comment: não vi em seu código as anotações `@Autowired` para habilitar a injeção de dependência do Spring. Estão faltando: 1) a injeção do serviço no controller e 2) a injeção do repositório no serviço. Você fez essa injeção?

Comment: Não cheguei a fazer, mas encontrei o problema aqui

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no repository nessas duas linhas aqui

```
public final static String FIND_USER_PASSWORDS = "SELECT * FROM TB_SENHA WHERE ID_USER = :idUser";
public final static String FIND_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM TB_SENHA WHERE ID_SENHA = :idSenha";
```

eu não sei o por que porem quando eu troquei o **"="** por **"like"**, funcionou ... e também troquei os tipos dos parâmetros de **UUID** para **String**, no final ficou assim :

```
public interface PasswordRepository extends JpaRepository<SenhaModel, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SenhaModel> {

    public final static String FIND_USER_PASSWORDS = "SELECT * FROM TB_SENHA WHERE ID_USER LIKE :idUser";
    public final static String FIND_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM TB_SENHA WHERE ID_SENHA LIKE :idSenha";

    @Query(value = FIND_USER_PASSWORDS, nativeQuery = true)
    public List<SenhaModel> findSenhasByIdUser(@Param("idUser") final String idUser);

    @Query(value = FIND_BY_ID, nativeQuery = true)
    public SenhaModel findByGuidId(@Param("idSenha") final String idSenha);
}
```